# Как установить python2.7 pip2.7 на macbook m1?

Tags: python-2.x, pip, macbook, m1

На текущий момент работаю с проектом, который использует python2, django1.9. Возникла необходимость в IDE (pycharm), поднять virtualenv.

Столкнулся с проблемой отсутствия pip на macbook с чипом m1. После долгих страданий и установки пип:

При вызове команды `pip install virtualenv` (pip, pip2, pip2.7) получаю ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==21.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 489, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2843, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2434, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2440, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-21.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 60
    sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")
```

Возможно кто-то сталкивался, как решали?

Comment: А другие пакеты кроме virtualenv устанавливаются?

Comment: @insolor сейчас всё снёс, а тогда устанавливались